# handling trailing \n when using feof()

Tags: c, loops, file-io

I have written a small program which takes input of a file such as:

```
13,22,13,14,31,22, 3, 1,12,10
11, 4,23, 7, 5, 1, 9,33,11,10
40,19,17,23, 2,43,35,21, 4,34
30,25,16,12,11, 9,87,45, 3, 1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

and outputs the largest sum of numbers on each line that is less than 50.

However if the inputted file has a trailing newline character the loop runs one too many times and hence another line is added to the array with random data. So I'm looking for a better way to do this comparison to avoid this issue. I'm also assuming all lines have 10 integers on at the moment as i cannot think of a better way to do the end of line loop comparison.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readLineData(int lineNo, int val[][10], FILE *fp);
int findSum(int lineNo, int val[][10], FILE *fp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  int val[5][10];

  // Open file.
  if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
    perror("Cannot open file ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


  for (int i = 0; !feof(fp); i++) // runs too many times if file ends with '\n'
    {
      readLineData(i, val, fp);
      printf("%d\n", findSum(i, val, fp));
    }

 fclose(fp);
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void readLineData(int lineNo, int val[][10], FILE *fp) {
  char c;  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // assuming line contains 10 integers
    {
      fscanf(fp, "%d,", &val[lineNo][i]);
    }
}

int findSum(int lineNo, int val[][10], FILE *fp) {
  int highVal = 0;
  int value1 = 0;
  int value2 = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //each letter
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)// every other letter
    {
      if((val[lineNo][i] + val[lineNo][j]) > highVal && i != j && (val[lineNo][i] + val[lineNo][j]) <= 50)
        {
          highVal = val[lineNo][i] + val[lineNo][j];
          value1 = val[lineNo][i];
          value2 = val[lineNo][j];
        }
    }
    }
  printf("Line %d: largest pair is %d and %d, with a total of: ", lineNo+1, value1, value2);
  return highVal;
}
```

any help with those loop comparisons and general notation tips is most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The posted code does not distinguish between two lines that have five integers and (the expected) one line that has 10 integers. Suggest reading in a line at a time, using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then using [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) on the read line to ensure that all the read integers belong to the same line.

Check the return value of input operations. For example, `sscanf()` (and `fscanf()`) return the number of assignments made. Only process lines that have the expected 10 integers, which would detect invalid lines including the trailing empty line.

For example:

```
/* Returns 1 on success and 0 on failure. */
int readLineData(int lineNo, int val[][10], FILE *fp)
{
    char line[1024]; /* Arbitrarily large. */
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        /* %n records position where processing ended. */
        int pos;
        const int result = sscanf(line,
                                  "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d%n",
                                  &val[lineNo][0],
                                  &val[lineNo][1],
                                  &val[lineNo][2],
                                  &val[lineNo][3],
                                  &val[lineNo][4],
                                  &val[lineNo][5],
                                  &val[lineNo][6],
                                  &val[lineNo][7],
                                  &val[lineNo][8],
                                  &val[lineNo][9],
                                  &pos);

        /* 10 integers and full line processed,
           except if new-line character present. */
        return 10 == result &&
               (pos == strlen(line) ||
                (pos + 1 == strlen(line) && '\n' == line[pos]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. The POSIX `getline` function is even better, although it is of course not portable to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply consume the newline character yourself:

```
for (int i = 0; !feof(fp); i++) // runs too many times if file ends with '\n'
{
  readLineData(i, val, fp);
  printf("%d\n", findSum(i, val, fp));
  fscanf(fp, "%*c"); // read a character without storing it in a variable
}
```

Note that there are undoubtedly better ways that involve reading an entire line at once and simply examining its contents; but this is the easiest way that will fit with what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

you could check if `fscanf` fails in your `readLineData` function:

```
int readLineData(int lineNo, int val[][10], FILE *fp) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {// assuming line contains 10 integers
     if (fscanf(fp, "%d,", &val[lineNo][i]) != 1) {
         return 1;
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```